# Microsoft Reporting Services Grouping equal rows

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, grouping

So I have 8 columns at all. 5 of them (`Company WorkShift Workshop Employee City`) are information about company, workshift, workshop, employee and city, other 3 are results of 2 tests and item for which these test was made (named as: `Item Test2 Test3`). Report's structure for now is something like this:

```
Company | WorkShift | Workshop | Empolyee | City  |  Item  | Test1 | Test2 |
____________________________________________________________________________
Comp1   | Shift1    | wshop1   | John     | etc   |    1   |   0   |   1   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Comp1   | Shift1    | wshop1   | John     | etc   |    2   |   1   |   1   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Comp1   | Shift1    | wshop1   | John     | etc   |    3   |   0   |   0   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Comp2   | Shift2    | wshop2   | Peter    | etc1  |    4   |   0   |   1   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Comp2   | Shift2    | wshop2   | Peter    | etc1  |    5   |   1   |   0   |
```

As you see first 3 rows have equal information about company, workshift, workshop, employee and item, so I need to add grouping something like this:

```
Company | WorkShift | Workshop | Empolyee | Item  | -- Grouped column names
___________________________________________________
Comp1   | Shift1    | wshop1   | John     | etc   | -- Grouped equal values
---------------------------------------------------
Item        |      Test2      |       Test3       | -- Column names with tests
___________________________________________________
1           |        0        |         1         |
---------------------------------------------------
2           |        1        |         1         | -- Tests results for group1
---------------------------------------------------
3           |        0        |         0         |
--------------------------------------------------- 
                                                  |
                                                  |
Company | WorkShift | Workshop | Empolyee | city  | -- Grouped column names
___________________________________________________
Comp2   | Shift2    | wshop2   | Peter    | etc1  | -- Grouped other equal values
---------------------------------------------------
Item        |      Test2      |       Test3       | -- Column names with tests
___________________________________________________
4           |        0        |         1         | 
--------------------------------------------------- -- Test results for group2
5           |        1        |         0         | 
---------------------------------------------------
```

Dataset for this report is stored procedure which returning data in following format as shown in `Report's structure'.

I've tried create new column with following expression:

```
=Fields!Company.Value & " " & Fields!WorkShift.Value & " " & Fields!Workshop.Value & " " & Fields!Employee.Value & " " & Fields!City.Value
```

And add below Tests columns.

But in this case It adding all information about `Company WorkShift Workshop Employee Item` in one field and not grouping by tests. Have you ideas?

**EDIT:**

And here is how Design window looks like:

```
Company  | WorkShift  | Workshop | Empolyee | City  |  Item  | Test1 | Test2 | -- Column names 
____________________________________________________________________________
[Company]|[WorkShift] |[Workshop]|[Employee]|[City] | [Item] |[Test1]|[Test2]| -- Values
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this is going to be little bit tricky, But here we go,

1) Right click `Company` cell -> Add row Group-> Parent group
2) Then select the company as the parent group
3) Then click on newly added cell of the company parent and right click and add child row group and row group on workshift
4) Then select newly created workshift column and then click on it and next child group for `workshop` do this for the `Employee` and `City`
5) Now make sure you are right click in the `CompanyGroup` cell and then select `Insert Row`-> `Inside group above` and add 2 rows
6) Then in newly added first row go under the company cell old one not the newly created grouped column and set the `Company` value there and in same row and old columns set the value for the `Workshift`,`Workshop`,`Employee`,`City`
7) Now delete the `Item`,`Test1`,`Test2` column
8) Then in second row which we added in step 5 set the  cell header as `Item`,'Test1','Test2'
9) And now the old row which was by default there which has values for the `Company` and other fields change the values to your respective columns as `Item`,`Test1` and `Test2`
10) Now delete the group column which we have added but make sure to delete only columns not the group on them when you delete the group column it will ask if you want to delete the associated group with it then select no. (Or you can hide them if you want)
11)  At the end there should be 5 columns(visible) and 4 rows (with header row)

This should do what you want.Let me know if any issues.

---

**UPDATE**

After 4th step your design should look like

```
 Company  | WorkShift  | Workshop | Empolyee | City  |  |Company  | WorkShift  | Workshop | Empolyee | City  |  Item  | Test1 | Test2 | -- Column names 
____________________________________________________________________________
 Company  | WorkShift  | Workshop | Empolyee | City  |  | [Company]|[WorkShift] |[Workshop]|[Employee]|[City] | [Item] |[Test1]|[Test2]| -- Values
```

First 5 columns are added using group on each time.

After 8th step the design should look like

[image]

Comment: Thank you for an answer. I have question about 5th step. What do you mean `ComkpanyGroup` cell? I need to right click on the new created parent `Company`? Or should I select parent and childs and then do right click? Also updated my question with `Design Window View`

Comment: Right click on the new created parent `Company`. Don't select the child's just the first parent cell of `Company`.

Comment: Ok, so If you look at my updated question I posted structure of `Design Window View`. After I add group (1-4 steps) It adding new columns, but with names `[Company]` istead of `Company`, etc. I'm asking just because I want to know If I'm doing It right.

Comment: Ok I got It after 4 step.

Comment: I think I passed 6th and 7th steps successfully. About 8 step: "set the cell header as `Item`, `Test1`, `Test2`" which cell header I should set?

Comment: Updated my question with screenshot how It looks like after 7 step. All right?

Comment: It seems going to work, but there is no repeating Header `Company  | WorkShift  | Workshop | Empolyee | City  |` before each group.

Comment: Set the text as `Item1`,`Test1`,`Test2` for the empty middle row. and then in the last row replace the values with the values you need

Comment: This got a problem, It's only adding headers 2 times (main header and 1 more) and later only values, I have for now 12 headers and It will increase in future.

Comment: I found why, that because `[Gamybos_cechas] (Company)` is the same in `3, 4, 5, 6... groups`, but other values are different so It should add new header, but if `[Gamybos_cechas]` is unique in some rows It grouping them

Comment: You need to add the 2 rows(Which we added in step 5) on that group cell for which you want group to change. I thought customer is your changing group thats why I said add it on that

Comment: How to do that? I think I did It - split cells.

Comment: You need to decide on which column's value change event you want to repeat the headers and on that grouping column do the step 5 instead of the `customer` column.

Comment: Here is problem if Parent Group have duplicates. So I have changed parent cell.